# R reads the path to a .app file as a folder on macOS

Tags: r, directory, filepath

Currently I am trialing a package that requires defining a path to where an external application is located. This application ([for anyone curious](http://dsi-studio.labsolver.org)) does not have a formal install and is simply a .app file to be placed in any given folder.

In R, I need to define a path to this file location, e.g.,

```
program_path <- ~/Desktop/Folder/dsi_studio.app
```

However, R interprets this as a folder, and thus when I try to run a few functions within the package, it claims the `program_path` I fed it is a directory and not a program/application.

Is there any way to force R to read this path as an application and not as a folder? I even went as far as defining `program_path` as the .app's Unix Executable File (i.e., dsi_studio.app/Contents/MacOS/dsi_studio), but no dice. I must be missing something here.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With that code you might be getting a result that is a formula rather than a text/character object. Try putting quotation marks around that file path. The `~` is actually a function to create an R formula object. You also might need `path.expand` since the `~` in MacOS is a shortcut for `/Users/user_name/`. Try instead:

```
program_path <- "~/Desktop/Folder/dsi_studio.app"
```